# adding new records to room database in kotlin

Tags: database, kotlin, android-room, dao, upsert

I have following entity to store database record

```
@Entity(tableName = "saves")
data class SaveEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "primary_key")
    val id: Int?,
    //rest of the fields
    )
```

Also there is dao interface

```
@Dao
interface SavesDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun upsert(entity:SaveEntity)
    //rest of the api
}
```

`upsert` method should update record or add new one if it doesn't exist.In the first case its clear - I get record from db, modify it and then update.But what about adding new entry? Where do I get value for primary key?
Do I have to do additional request to get total number of records in database?Then what the purpose of primary key autogeneration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your SQL rule : (onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
>     already says that if another entity with the same id is found it will be replaced by the new entity.

your use case is not clear though, your id's are auto-generated so although two objects may have the same attributes they can have a different id. the only case they would be considered the same is if you picked the entity from your room database and tried to modify it and put it back.

If you still want the `upsert() function` for updating any certain field of an existing entity, do not make upsert an SQLite query method rather make it as a wrapper function that contains the logic for your insert or update.

> For example:

```
@Dao
interface SavesDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(entity:SaveEntity)

    @Query("UPDATE item SET like_count = :likeCount WHERE ID = :id")
    fun updateLike(id: String, likeCount: Int)

    @Query("SELECT * from item WHERE id= :id")
    fun getItemById(id:Int):SaveEntity

    fun upsert(item:SaveEntity){
        val item = getItemById(item.id)
        if(item==null){
            insert(item)
        }else{
            updateLike(item.id, item.like+1)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm ok with update logic.The question is about inserting new entry.For instance user starts new game and saves it.I have to create new `SaveEntity` object.What do I pass in `id` parameter?

Comment: do not pass anything in the id field it will auto-increment each time a new `game` is created. When the user tries to continue previously saved `game` that will come from the database then you can update any field required, again here you do not have to pass the id as it will be the same room will handle that logic.

Comment: ouch I forgot `id` is nullable.It seems to add ok with `id=null`.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your use case is a typical/classic DB plain SQL. You don't have to manage the id's or autoincrement, in this case, SQLite does it for you. From SQLite documentation (links below), you can read:

> By default, every row in SQLite has a special column, usually called the "rowid", that uniquely identifies that row within the table.

you can read more [here](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html).

Can also help read the [SQLite Autoincrement](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) to understand the implications of using AUTOINCREMENT explicitly or of using INTEGER PRIMARY KEYs.

**References:**

- [Accessing data using Room DAOs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#kotlin) (how insert and update works)
- [OnConflictStrategy](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/OnConflictStrategy.html#REPLACE) (how onConflict REPLACE works)

Hope it helps!

Comment: But I have to pass some id into entity constructor.In case it will be id of existing record upsert method will update it instead of creating new one.Isn't it so?

Comment: When you insert a record, the DB will check the primary keys (and constrains) for the table you are inserting. Also, when you update it checks teh primnary keys to find a record to update. So, if you use @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE), i believe it does the same: it find the correct record to "update" (since you are using OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE). You can test this way: the insert will return a long corresponding to the rowid of the inserted/updated row. By checking that id, you can verify that 1) insert is finding the correct id to "update"; 2) its updating the right one.